# Oracle 11.2.0.1.0 does not support APPLY

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, oracle11g

i have shift my database sql to oracle .now i have face some issue in queries which work for sql but not for oracle. i am working in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.
below is the part of query which have problem.

```
 return (from ac in db.action
 let dbobj = db.table.Where(X => X.tableid == 15).FirstOrDefault()
```